# Store files permanently in iOS device

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, file-management, nsdocumentdirectory

I need to store files(text/pdf) to the device memory permanently. If I write to documents directory, my files get erased once my app is uninstalled. So I need an isolated directory, like the gallery. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Files stored using NSFileManager, Core Data, SQLite etc etc are all cleared once the app is deleted. Using a web service is probably the best way, though there is admittedly a rather crude way if you make the document into an image by saving the context as a png or jpg. If so then you could save the image to the device's photo library using         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil); This is providing the app user allows the app access to their photo library. Like others have mentioned though, some sort of web service is your best bet if you really need this

Answer (score 3):

Since Apps live in Sandboxes you can not store files outside the App´s Sandbox. You could use iCloud or another Backup System and from there the user could restore the files when the App was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, [you can't](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html), and that is for a good reason. There would be no way for the user to control how much memory you are using, nor a way for them to free that memory. Your documents *should* be removed when the app is removed. If you need persistent storage, store it *yourself*, on a remote server; don't try to pollute the user's device.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the UIDocumentInteractionController

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/

As far as I know this is the only way.